# Proving a bijective correspondence between a set of equivalence classes $A^*$ and a set $B$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

> Let $f : A \to B$ be a surjective function. Let us define a relation on $A$ by setting $a_0$ ~ $a_1$ if $f(a_0) = f(a_1)$. This relation is an equivalence relation. Let $A^*$ be the set of equivalence classes. Show that there is a bijective correspondence of $A^*$ with $B$

Now if $E$ is an equivalence class, then $E = A^*$, as two equivalence classes are either equal or disjoint. So $A^* =  \{a_i :a_i$ ~ $a_j \} = \{a_i : f(a_i) = f(a_j)\}$

I need to prove that $f$ needs to be both surjective and injective to prove a bijective correspondence between $A^*$ and $B$. But I'm not sure how to go about doing so, in this specific case, Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Your first statement below the problem makes no sense. $A^*$ is the set of equivalence classes, so if $E$ is an equivalence class, then $E\in A^*$ and therefore is certainly not equal to $A^*$. For each $a\in A$ let $[a]=\{x\in A:f(x)=f(a)\}$; this is the equivalence class of $a$. Then $A^*=\{[a]:a\in A\}$.

Comment: Observe that the restriction of $f$ to $A^*$ is bijective.

Comment: @BrianMScott, You're correct I made a mistake, just to check my understanding if $E_i$ is an equivalence class, then is the following correct? $$\cup_{i} E_i = A^*$$

Comment: Each equivalence class is an element of $A^*$, not a subset.

Comment: @Masacroso; There is no restriction of $f$ to $A^*$, as $A^*$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: @Bernard by choosing one representative for each equivalence class in $A^*$, we may easily define an injection from $A^*$ to $A$. We naturally think of this map as an inclusion, and thus we think of $A^*$ as a subset of $A$. One should note, however, that this inclusion is not canonical or unique.

Comment: @Bernard I know, but I dont had a best wording. We can say instead _the restriction of the induced function $f$ over $\mathcal P(A)$ to $A^*\subset\mathcal P(A)$ is bijective_

Comment: I'd simply call it the *quotient map*.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A^*=\{A_i\}$ the set of equivalence classes for $f$. We define a map $\bar f\colon A^*\longrightarrow B$ by $\;\bar f (A_i)=f(\text{any}\enspace x\in A_i)$.

This map is well defined by construction, since all elements in an equivalence class have the same image.

It is injective, for  if $\bar f(A_i)=\bar f(A_j)$, for any elements $x\in A_i$  and $y\in A_j$, we have $f(x)=f(y)$. This means $x\sim y$, hence $A_i=A_j$.

Finall, if we denote $\pi\colon A\longrightarrow A^*$ the canonical map $x\longmapsto [x]$, we have, by construction, $\;f=\bar f\circ \pi$. It is well known that if the composition of two maps is surjective, the second (in order of composition) is surjective. Hence $\bar f$ surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can define a new function $\overline{f}: A^* \to B$ by $$\overline{f}([a]) = f(a)$$

I claim that $\overline{f}$ is a bijection. To prove this, you'll need to show that:

1. $\overline{f}$ is a well-defined function (does it depend on how we represented the class $[a]$?)
2. $\overline{f}$ is injective
3. $\overline{f}$ is surjective